# Show conversations in a user chat profile in two columns

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-bookmarks, conversation

When a conversation is bookmarked in chat, it is added to two places:

- Conversation tab in the room info - [example](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=conversations).
- Conversation tab in the user profile of the user who bookmarked it - [example](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard?tab=conversations).

As you can see if you look at the examples, the conversations for the room are shown in two columns. For a user, there is only one column - with lot of empty space on the right. (On purpose, I chose as an example a user who has a lot of bookmarks, so it takes quite a lot of scrolling to get to the end. Changing the display in two columns would halve the amount of scrolling.)

**Suggestion:** Display the conversations in user profiles in two columns - similarly as for the chatrooms.

Comment: Oh hey, it's me! :-D

Comment: The CSS is already present in both cases, but the `div` containing the list is missing a `id="conversations-list"` for the user list. Adding that missing `id` gets it to display in two columns (https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3V3R.png). I think this is more [tag:bug] than [tag:feature-request].

Comment: It used to be shown in two columns in both places.  It's been broken for a while, but I haven't gone looking for bug reports.